# prepend a string to a column value before specific character in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Imagine I have a table which has a **Params** column and it contains settings of my gallery. I want to add 2 other properties automatically with MySQL query.
I have already test this query but it will add my new properties at the first of the column value which is incorrect :

```
UPDATE table 
SET params=CONCAT(',  "slider_fullscreen_button_skin": "myTheme", "slider_zoompanel_skin": "myTheme"',params)
WHERE params NOT LIKE '%myTheme%';
```

let's say I have this value on my column :

```
{"title":"Bessariabian","alias":"Bessariabian","category":"1103","full_width":"false"}
```

I want my value change to something like this:

```
{"title":"Bessariabian","alias":"Bessariabian","category":"1103","full_width":"false", "slider_fullscreen_button_skin": "myTheme", "slider_zoompanel_skin": "myTheme"}
```

I want to make a query which adds the new properties at the end of the value before **}** location.
How I can handle this?

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output

Comment: OK, let's say I have this value on my column :
`{"title":"Bessariabian","alias":"Bessariabian","category":"1103","full_width":"false"}`

I want my value change to something like this:
`{"title":"Bessariabian","alias":"Bessariabian","category":"1103","full_width":"false",  "slider_fullscreen_button_skin": "myTheme", "slider_zoompanel_skin": "myTheme"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [Substring_Index()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function to get the Substring before the first occurence of `}`.
- Now, [Concat()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) this substring with your required string, and `}` at the end.

Try:

```
UPDATE table 
SET params = CONCAT(
                    SUBSTRING_INDEX(params, '}', 1), 
                    ',  "slider_fullscreen_button_skin": "myTheme", "slider_zoompanel_skin": "myTheme"', 
                    '}'
                   )
WHERE params NOT LIKE '%myTheme%';
```

Comment: @BabakHabibi happy to help :)